# Cannot use Visual Soft Crypt in .Net Environment

Tags: .net, components, activex

We are using an Active X component called Visual Soft Crypt (VisualSoftCrypt.dll) in a VB 6.0 application. We are converting the application to a VB.Net. I cannot get this dll to work. I can register it on my machine but I get this error: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {677EA3B8-D22B-4743-8746-D9A03EABA946} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))." 
The suggested solution in another thread of changing my platform to x86 does not work.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Is there a .Net version of this component or some other way to accomplish the same results?

Comment: You should use modern encryption algorithms (PGP or NaCl).  That uses old and broken algorithms.

Comment: Also, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'd love to do that. Unfortunately, I have to decrypt files that were encryption with the Visual Soft Crypt component. I either have to use it or figure out exactly what it is doing.

Comment: Try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledescryptoserviceprovider.aspx